# what documents needed at airport to arrive in Canada by air and transfer to cruise ship?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, paperwork, cruising

I am a caucasian flying from US to Vancouver, transferring to cruise ship for Alaska.  I have a DUI on my record. Do I need anything other than passport since I am not staying in Canada?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Sorry but caucasian is not a nationality.

Answer (score 3):

You will quite possibly need a great many more documents than just your passport.  Canada is quite strict about people with criminal records, and in particular, [drunk driving is a federal offense under Canadian Law.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impaired_driving_in_Canada)  Moreover, you will necessarily need to pass Canadian Customs to get from the airport to the cruise ship terminal;  as far as I know, there's no "transit visa" exception for a situation like this.

You can try to get in to Canada with a criminal record;  the customs officer you talk to can declare you ["deemed rehabilitated":](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/inadmissibility/rehabilitation.asp)

> You may be deemed rehabilitated, depending on:
>
> - the crime you committed
> - how serious the crime was and how much time has passed since you completed the sentence imposed for your crime:
>
>   - 10 years for one indictable offence
>   - five years for two or more summary convictions
> - whether you have committed one or more crimes and
> - if the crime would be punishable in Canada by a maximum prison term of less than 10 years.
>
> ...
>
> If you think you are eligible, be sure you have these documents if you travel to Canada:
>
> - passport or birth certificate plus photo identification
> - a copy of court documents for each conviction, and proof that all sentences were completed
> - a recent criminal record check
> - a recent police certificate from the country where you were convicted and from anywhere you have lived for six (6) months or longer in the last 10 years.

[This checklist](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5507E.pdf) implies that U.S. residents should have a certificate from each state in which they have lived in addition to a federal FBI certificate.

Even if you have all of this documentation, deemed rehabilitation at a port of entry is not guaranteed;  ultimately, it's up to the judgement of the customs officer you talk to.  If you really want to ensure that you will be admitted to Canada, you will have to [apply for rehabilitation.](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/inadmissibility/conviction.asp)  This is a longer process, requires a non-refundable C$200 processing fee, and (according to the above link) can take over a year to complete.

For a brief visit, you can also apply for a [temporary visitor permit](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/inadmissibility/permits.asp).  You can even apply for this permit even if it has not yet been five years since your conviction.  This normally seems to require a non-refundable C$200 processing fee as well;  however, it [may be possible to get a permit without the fee.](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=143&top=8)  I haven't yet found any information on how to avoid paying this fee, though.

Finally, all of this is independent of whether or not you would normally need a visa to enter Canada.  U.S. citizens do not typically require a visa for brief visits to Canada, but if you are a citizen of another country, you may need one after all.  I will leave the details of this to another answerer.

Comment: The temporary visitor permit can also be issued _at the border_, where it seems a fee does not apply.